# c++ sparse vector

Tags: c++, vector, operations

Question 1)

I have a large sparse vector of doubles in c++, I need to efficiently parse out the indices of the non zero elements from the vector. I can obviously loop over the length and do it, any better way to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you have a second question, make a second post.

Comment: I mention it right, its trivial to loop over it and solve. is there a better way ?

Comment: There's no standard sparse vector in C++. It is unclear what you mean. Do you have some data structure (which, and what is meant by "parsing out")? A data file (in which format, and what kind of data structure you want to create?) Something else?

Comment: sorry sparse means that the vector say is 200 long, but mostly is 0's

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some special knowledge of the makeup of the vector of doubles, (for example, it's sorted), a loop over its entirety is the most efficient you're gonna get.

Of course, a change in structure as suggested by eladidan is probably something you should consider.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a large sparse vector of doubles in c++, I need to efficiently parse out the indices of the non zero elements from the vector. I can obviously loop over the length and do it, any better way to do it?

If the vector is truly sparse (`n = o(N)` where `n` is the number of non-zero elements and `N` is the size of the vector), then representing it in an `std::map<int,double>` or `std::unordered_map<int,double>` is probably best. With `std::map`way you get to find an element in `O(log(n))` . With `std::unordered_map` a find operation takes amortized time of `O(1)`. In both cases, the number of non-zero elements is simply the size of the container. Both approaches also take `O(n)` space instead of `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot [change the representation of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924175/430766), you have to examine each element to filter out those that are [almost equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon#Example) to zero. However, this task is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), so maybe you can partition the workload to a bunch of threads to at least improve the runtime (although not the complexity).